# How to highlight duplicate text string within a column

Tags: google-sheets

My team are using Google Sheets to schedule engineers to their jobs.

I would like the sheet to highlight to me when we have scheduled an engineer twice within 1 day; my problem is, we are often adding more than 1 engineer within each cell, so the usual DUPLICATE VALUES would not work.

I managed to get the sheet to say YES at the top when their initials appear somewhere in the column below - but I cannot work out how to make it highlight somehow when they appear more than once.

I hope this makes some sense, I have attached a screenshot of the sheet if that helps:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

<sub>This formula (**Formula 3** below), assumes consistent names. See **Formula 4** for alternatives</sub>

```
=MAP(F2:F13, LAMBDA(n,
   BYCOL(LS21:ME693, LAMBDA(d, 
     IFNA(
       LET(
         count,SUMPRODUCT(
           REGEXMATCH(d, "(^|\s)"& n &"($|\s)"))>1,
         "Dup", "Yes"))))))
```

## Formula Examples

- Formulas go in **`LR2`** or whatever column has the first date column.
- Formulas will return an empty value if the name is not found, **`Yes`** if name is found once, **`Dup`** if the name is found more than once.
- Replace **`dayRng`** and **`nameRng`** with the appropriate range references for example **`F2`** or **`F2:F13`** and **`LS21:LS693`** or **`LS21:ME693`** depending on the formula used.
- LAMBDA variable names where included can be changed.  I chose them for clarity over brevity. For example, **`oneName`** vs. **`n`** and **`oneDay`** vs. **`d`**

#### 1.   One Day, One Name   `[dayRng]`, `[nameRng]`

```
=IFNA(
   IF(
     SUMPRODUCT(
       REGEXMATCH(dayRng, "(^|\s)"& nameRng &"($|\s)"))>1,
     "Yes",))
```

#### 2.   One Day, Multiple Names   `[dayRng]`, `[nameRng]`

```
=MAP(nameRng, LAMBDA(oneName, 
   IFNA(
     IF(
       SUMPRODUCT(
         REGEXMATCH(dayRng, "(^|\s)"& oneName &"($|\s)"))>1,
       "Dup", "Yes"))))
```

#### 3.   Multiple Days, Multiple Names   `[dayRng]`, `[nameRng]`

```
=MAP(nameRng, LAMBDA(oneName,
   BYCOL(dayRng, LAMBDA(oneDay, 
     IFNA(
       IF(
         SUMPRODUCT(
           REGEXMATCH(oneDay, "(^|\s)"& oneName &"($|\s)"))>1,
         "Dup", "Yes",))))))
```

#### 4.   Multiple Days, Multiple Names w/ regex   `[dayRng]`, `[nameRng]`

- Your names contain first names and the values you are checking contain initials.
- The simplest solution would to use consistent values.
- You could also approach this in other ways like including the intials in parentheses with the names. If you had **`Oliver (OB)`** or **`Oliver Benson (OB)`** you could then use the regular expression `"((\w*))"` to return the initials.

```
=MAP(nameRng, LAMBDA(oneName,
   BYCOL(dayRng, LAMBDA(oneDay, 
     IFNA(
       IF(
         SUMPRODUCT(
           REGEXMATCH(oneDay, "(^|\s)"& 
             REGEXEXTRACT(oneName, "\((\w*)\)") &"($|\s)"))>1,
         "Dup", "Yes",))))))
```

Comment: Amazing so many ways to solve. I just bookmarked !